# An exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm getting this error when attempting to cancel and restart a `Task` using [this](https://johnthiriet.com/cancel-asynchronous-operation-in-csharp/) as my guide. What isn't clear to me is why the error occurs despite a try / catch.

**What Should Happen**

The code is designed to run a search task after a user enters a value into the textbox following a 1 second delay. However, if the user continues typing after the delay, I'd like to cancel the task and restart it.

**Code in the Main Window (PMSearch) to start the Task**

Firing up the task works. Here's the code:

```
    CancellationTokenSource CancellationSource;
    Task ActiveTask;

    private void SearchTermEntered(object sender, string searchText)
    {
         ...do some stuff
         _ = SearchAsync();
    }

    private async Task SearchAsync()
    {
        CancelSearch(null,null);
        CancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        SearchManager sMan = new SearchManager();
        try
        {
            var searchTask = sMan.SearchPDFAsync(SearchTerm, CancellationSource.Token);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Task");
            var results = await searchTask;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Results: " + results.ToString());
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled: " + ex.Task.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Code to Cancel the Task**

This is the handler to cancel the task.

```
    private void CancelSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Called when user continues to enter text.
        CancellationSource?.Cancel();
    }
```

**The Async Code Run by the Task**

```
    public Task<decimal> SearchPDFAsync(string searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<decimal> task = null;
        task = Task.Run(() =>
        {

            decimal result = 0;

            // Loop for a defined number of iterations
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                // HERE IS WHERE I'M TOLD THERE IS AN UNHANDLED EXCEPTION
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) throw new TaskCanceledException(task);

                // Do something that takes times like a Thread.Sleep in .NET Core 2.
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                result += i;
            }

            return result;
        });

        return task;
    }
```

**The Error**

I'm receiving the error in `SearchPDFAsync` at: `if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) throw new TaskCanceledException(task);` As I understand it, the exception is the proper design pattern. What's unclear is why the exception's 'unhandled' when the code is nestled inside a try / catch in `PMSearch.SearchAsync()`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**
For clarity, I've combined the code into one class.

Note a few changes - I've converted `SearchTermEntered` to an async method.

```
   private async void SearchTermEntered(object sender, string searchText)
    {
        //Refreshes the topics listbox as new values are entered
        SearchTerm = searchText.ToLower();

        stkPnlTopics.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        stkPnlMetrics.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        stkPnlResources.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (SearchTerm.Length <= 2) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
        {
            stkPnlTopics.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            txtBlkTopics.Text = "";
        }
        else if (SearchTerm.IsNumeric() || GLSearchPatterns.Contains(SearchTerm))
        { 
            //user is searching for a guideline
            txtBlkTopics.Text = "Guidelines";
            stkPnlTopics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            await SearchAsync();
        }
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstBxTopics.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

Two changes here:

- I put the for loop inside `SearchAsync`
- By the advice offered below, I changed the cancellation check to `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` which is meant to yield an `OperactionCanceledException'

  ```
  private async Task SearchAsync()
  {
      CancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      try
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Task");
          await Task.Run(() =>
          {
              decimal result = 0;
              // Loop for a defined number of iterations
              for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
              {
                  // Check if a cancellation is requested, if yes,
                  // throw a TaskCanceledException.
                  CancellationSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                  // Do something that takes times like a Thread.Sleep in .NET Core 2.
                  Thread.Sleep(10);
                  result += i;
              }

              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString());
          });
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException)
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Op cancelled exception.");
      }
  }

  private void CancelSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancel Search");
      CancellationSource?.Cancel();
  }
  ```

Even in this format, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Michael Randall's response, I was forced to await everything. It's ugly, but it works.

The key changes:

- `SearchTermEntered` is now an async handler
- `SearchAsync()` is called with await
- `Task.Run` is called with await *and* its anonymous function called with async

  ```
      private async void SearchTermEntered(object sender, string searchText)
      {
          //Refreshes the topics listbox as new values are entered
          SearchTerm = searchText.ToLower();

          stkPnlTopics.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          stkPnlMetrics.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          stkPnlResources.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

          if (SearchTerm.Length <= 2) return;
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
          {
              stkPnlTopics.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
              txtBlkTopics.Text = "";
          }
          else if (SearchTerm.IsNumeric() || GLSearchPatterns.Contains(SearchTerm))
          { 
              //user is searching for a guideline
              txtBlkTopics.Text = "Guidelines";
              stkPnlTopics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          }
          else
          {
              await SearchAsync();
          }

          CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstBxTopics.ItemsSource).Refresh();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming
      /// </summary>
      private async Task SearchAsync()
      {
          CancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
          try
          {
              //SearchManager sMan = new SearchManager();
              //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Task");
              //var results = await sMan.GetArtifactsWithSearchValAsync(SearchTerm, CancellationSource.Token);
              //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Results: " + results.ToString());

              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Task");
              await Task.Run(async () =>
              {
                  decimal result = 0;
                  // Loop for a defined number of iterations
                  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                  {
                      // Check if a cancellation is requested, if yes,
                      // throw a TaskCanceledException.
                      CancellationSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                      // Do something that takes times like a Thread.Sleep in .NET Core 2.
                      //Thread.Sleep(10);
                      await Task.Delay(10);
                      result += i;
                  }

                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString());
              });
          }
          catch (OperationCanceledException)
          {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Op cancelled exception.");
          }
      }

      private void CancelSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancel Search");
          CancellationSource?.Cancel();
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

## Update

<sub>***Note** : The question has been updated significantly since this was answered*.</sub>

When *eliding a task*, there is a subtle difference in how *exceptions* are handled.

<sub>See Stephen Cleary's blog on [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).</sub>

The best approach would be to just make this all `async`. This will allow the *exception* to be placed on the *task*, and in-turn be *thrown* and be *caught* where you expect it

```
public async Task<decimal> SearchPDFAsync(string searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {

        decimal result = 0;

        // Loop for a defined number of iterations
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            // HERE IS WHERE I'M TOLD THERE IS AN UNHANDLED EXCEPTION
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) throw new TaskCanceledException(task);

            // since we are async we can use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep 
            await Task.Delay(10);
            result += i;
        }

        return result;
    });
}
```

However, depending on your workload (and whether this is a CPU bound) this should probably just be a `sync` and the `task` run when calling the *method*.

<sub>See Stephen Cleary's blog on [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)</sub>

Another (less eloquent) solution, is to capture the *exception* and place it on the *task*, this will throw the *exception* when the method is *awaited*, and more closely follows what the compiler generated `IAsyncStateMachine` will implement when using the *async and await pattern*

```
public Task<decimal> SearchPDFAsync(string searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   try
   {

      return Task.Run(() => {
         ...
      });

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return Task.FromException<decimal>(ex);
   }
}
```

And lastly, you may not need to *throw* inside the *task* at all, and just *return* something the task is *cancelled* .

---

**Update 2**

If you are making a auto complete search box, tasks are fine, though you might also want to look at *Reactive Extensions (RX)*, they have some great extensions for denouncing and throttling, and lots more.

---

**Original**

It's not catching, because the `Exception` is *unobserved* due to your `Task.Run`. Think about it, you're asking someone to run-off and complete a *task*, then walking away and wondering why (if they have a problem) you don't know about it.

```
task = Task.Run(() =>
```

<sub>***Note** : I misunderstood the code.*</sub>

Comment: From the article I linked, the try/catch is outside the Task.Run. Note that I do use await, too: `var results = await searchTask` where searchTask is set to the function running the Task (`SearchPDFAsync`)

Comment: Interesting. Applying your first suggestion in my edit above, this appears to work. The one thing to note is that to await Task.Delay, I had to make the anoynmous function in Run async: `await Task.Run(_async_ () => ...`

Comment: It may be I move away from async / await entirely following your other recommendation. Not sure how that implementation would work yet, given I'd like to create a dynamic search bar that restarts as users enter new terms. Appreciate the help either way.